# Beginner programmer for Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Looking for help to solve this, I think the issue is with line 7 adding the two values. I have not had much luck solving this issue unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```py
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, number_of_seeds):
        self.number_of_seeds = number_of_seeds

green_apple = Apple(number_of_seeds=10)
red_apple = Apple(number_of_seeds=20)
print(f'{green_apple + red_apple}')
```

Comment: improve your indentation. What is the problem?

Comment: You can't add two Apple instances together. What do you want `print(f'{green_apple + red_apple}')` to output?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just add the two `Apple` instances together as that's not defined, but you can add together the `Apple.number_of_seeds`, as that is just integer addition. For example:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, number_of_seeds):
        self.number_of_seeds = number_of_seeds

green_apple = Apple(number_of_seeds=10)
red_apple = Apple(number_of_seeds=20)
print (red_apple.number_of_seeds + green_apple.number_of_seeds)
# 30
```

Or, you could define a print method (either `__str__` or `__repr__`) and an `__add__` method, but this is a bit more advanced to implement:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, number_of_seeds):
        self.number_of_seeds = number_of_seeds
    def __add__(self, other_apple):
        self.number_of_seeds += other_apple.number_of_seeds
        return self.number_of_seeds
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.number_of_seeds)

green_apple = Apple(number_of_seeds=10)
red_apple = Apple(number_of_seeds=20)
print(f'{green_apple + red_apple}')
# 30
```

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
green_apple=Apple(10)
red_apple=Apple(20)
```